# git diff produces different results when used on full repo vs a single file

Tags: git, diff, moodle, patch

We try to create a patch file with the changes between two moodle versions.

This is what we did

```
$ git clone https://github.com/moodle/moodle.git
$ cd moodle
$ git diff  v3.8.1...v3.11.0 > /tmp/upgrade3_8_1__3_11_0.patch
```

But when we verify this file the patch seems odd:

```
$ grep " a/version.php" /tmp/upgrade3_8_1__3_11_0.patch -A 13
diff --git a/version.php b/version.php
index 6806d4e84d7..9c4d48bbb41 100644
--- a/version.php
+++ b/version.php
@@ -29,9 +29,9 @@
 
 defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
 
-$version  = 2019111800.00;              // 20191118      = branching date YYYYMMDD - do not modify!
+$version  = 2021051700.00;              // 20210517      = branching date YYYYMMDD - do not modify!
                                     //         RR    = release increments - 00 in DEV branches.
                                     //           .XX = incremental changes.
-$release  = '3.8 (Build: 20191118)'; // Human-friendly version name
-$branch   = '38';                       // This version's branch.
+$release  = '3.11 (Build: 20210517)';// Human-friendly version name
+$branch   = '311';                      // This version's branch.
```

*Problem:*

It should be

```
-$release  = '3.8.1 ...
```

Instead of

```
-$release  = '3.8 ...
```

If we execute the command on version.php only, it produces the expected results:

```
$ git diff v3.8.1..v3.11.0 version.php
diff --git a/version.php b/version.php
index 93c45b4ab93..9c4d48bbb41 100644
--- a/version.php
+++ b/version.php
@@ -29,9 +29,9 @@
 
 defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die();
 
-$version  = 2019111801.00;              // 20191118      = branching date YYYYMMDD - do not modify!
+$version  = 2021051700.00;              // 20210517      = branching date YYYYMMDD - do not modify!
                                     //         RR    = release increments - 00 in DEV branches.
                                     //           .XX = incremental changes.
-$release  = '3.8.1 (Build: 20200113)'; // Human-friendly version name
-$branch   = '38';                       // This version's branch.
+$release  = '3.11 (Build: 20210517)';// Human-friendly version name
+$branch   = '311';                      // This version's branch.
 $maturity = MATURITY_STABLE;             // This version's maturity level.
```

How can that be?

How can we create the right patch?

Sidenode: We even had one - unreproducible case - where `git diff v3.8.1..v3.11.0 version.php` also showed the wrong result. Shoudln't the output be deterministic? Does it depend on the current branch?

```
$ git --version
git version 2.25.1
```

This was configured before:

```
git config diff.renameLimit 999999
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 3 dots `...`, which is different from using `..`. Probably the common ancestor for those 2 revisions is 3.8 and that's why you see the revision set like that.

And, when diffing the file, you are using `..`. Try with `...` and you will get the same *"unexpected"* result.

Comment: That explains why I got different results on `git diff v3.8.1..v3.11.0 version.php` - I used it once with tree dots and was to blind to see this.

Comment: Note that the Git project folks are trying to convince people to move from `git diff A..B` to `git diff A B`. It does exactly the same thing, but (1) reads better and (2) is one whole character shorter (HUGELY IMPORTANT ).